# RavenDb - Cannot Store Due to Duplicate Property Name

Tags: ravendb

I'm trying to store a document in Raven - but a subclass hides a property on a base class - same name but different type. When I try and save it, I get this error:

"A member with the name 'User' already exists on 'Account'. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name

However, the class is sealed and I don't own it or cannot extend it. Do I have any options at all?

Comment: The page [here](http://ravendb.net/documentation/docs-custom-serialization) explains how to use `JsonPropertyAttribute` as per the error message. You should be able to use that to solve your issue.

Comment: did you read the question?

Comment: ;-) No I guess not, just re-read it and I see the issue

Comment: ok that's cool. I do that all the time too

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the class that you are trying to store, you can set the JsonContract (on the DocumentConventions) and modify how it gets serialized from there.